# React Native "imports"

Tags: ios, react-native

I am trying to develop a react-native book-searching app and have found this online as a helper tool: https://www.appcoda.com/react-native-introduction/

However, the site is from 2015, so some of the syntax is not properly updated.

I've run into the following issue:

The code that they tell me to use is as follows:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var Books = require('./Books');
var Search = require('./Search');

var {
    AppRegistry,
    TabBarIOS,
    Component
   } = React;
```

When I used that, I arrived at an Error Message telling me to use 
    import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
instead of
    import React from 'react-native';

In my attempt to update it to the latest version of React, I arrived at:

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';

var Books = require('./Books');
var Search = require('./Search');

var {
    AppRegistry,
    TabBarIOS
   } = React;
```

This is still causing multiple errors. Can someone explain how to properly do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to import AppRegistry and TabBarIOS from React instead of react-native and some syntax errors. Change:

```
var {
    AppRegistry,
    TabBarIOS
   } = React;
```

to

```
import {
    AppRegistry,
    TabBarIOS
   } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: instead of the requires, you can also do `import Books from './Books'`, same thing with Search if you're export defaulting them.